# Virtuemart payment plugin override

Tags: plugin, joomla3.8

I'm trying to override the "vmpayment" plugin. I've changed the layout of the "post_payment.php" file and put the file in the following folder structure: templates/mytemplate/html/plg_vmpayment_standard_standard/post_payment.php

Now this is not working. The structure of the plugin is:
plugins/vmpayment/standard/standard/post_payment.php

What am I missing here? I've changed it to exclude the last "standard" folder without success.

Comment: Have you read this documentation? https://docs.virtuemart.net/tutorials/templating-layouts/101-how-to-overwrite-plugins.html

Answer (score 1):

When the Virtuemart plugin has a second folder with the same name in it, then it is using the overridable pattern.

Copy this second folder to:
/templates/[yourtemplate]/html/[plugin-group]/[plugin-name]

So the right path would be:
/templates/[yourtemplate]/html/vmpayment/standard/post_payment.php

Official Documentation: [How to overwrite plugins](https://docs.virtuemart.net/tutorials/templating-layouts/101-how-to-overwrite-plugins.html)